# TypeError: stepNavigator.setHash is not a function in checkout Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, console

> **TypeError: stepNavigator.setHash is not a function**

I have a javascript error in the console like above, because of this error some shipping method is not showing properly.

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this error?

I am using **Magento 2.2.6.**

Comment: have you made any modifications to checkout steps like added new step ?

Comment: problem in adding in js so please share js code in your question

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar, not new step is added.

Comment: @RakeshDonga, I am not added any js code there, which file code i need to share please?

Comment: @jafarpinjar added new shipping method ?

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar, yes i added but that module i disabled now.

Comment: @jafarpinjar , Try clear pub/static and var/* and static content deploy , This usually happens when your shipping_method code does not match in your renderer

Comment: run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f ` this command

Comment: @RakeshDonga, Yes i did it, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Do you have added your own design or made a copy of the exist Luma theme?

In my case was this the problem.

Following JS was changed in the original path: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/step-navigator.js`.

I updated my `step-navigator.js` file in my theme and it worked.

I hope this will help you :)

PS: I made always Magento updates via composer. Actually this tested with Magento 2.2.8.